# Isolating radium oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

Why is radium oxide yet to be isolated when a wide range of other radium (II) compounds are known ?

Comment: I'd guess that not only is it radioactive, but that it is extremely reactive with water to produce the hydroxide salt.  So trying to isolate "pure" radium oxide is probably very difficult.

Comment: Anneal radium in an oxygen or oxygen + inert gas atmosphere ? Seems pretty trivial to me.

Comment: [BaO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barium_oxide) is created from BaO2 in over 1175K, this would be even worse in case of RaO, I guess.